# MUI [TreeView] scroll selected item into view

Tags: treeview, scrollview

In controlled mode programmatically selecting a TreeView item will not scroll such item into view.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thank you

The correct solution will probably use this somehow:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

First determine if selected node is already in view and then if not call scrollIntoView().